# How to Insert/Remove/Update UITableView without it appearing to move?

Tags: cocoa-touch, uitableview, uiscrollview, scroll

After reading [this](http://theinvisibl.com/2011/01/24/iphonemail/), I'm interested in being able to dynamically update a UITableView without the view scrolling. That is, if the 12th row is visible, and some background process runs and calls for a new row to be inserted at position 0, how can that be done without the table appearing to scroll?

The closest I've been able to come to achieving this is to do any and all updates in a single `-beginUpdates`/`-endUpdates` block and to adjust the `contentOffset` as appropriate after that. But some of my code might have a bunch of calls to `-insertRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation` called outside such a block, and when I do that, the thing can scroll all over the place.

How can I make UITableView stand still?